# RxSwift With UiTextField

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Im new to RxSwift and what Im trying is perform the following,

- User type is search UiTextField
- App must wait 1 sec after user finish typing to make sure not to hit the Api with each letter write or delete button pressed.
- App hit my Api for search

I tried the below code as example

```
class DestinationSearch: UIViewController {
    

    let searchTF = UITextField()    
    var disposeBag = DisposeBag()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUpUI()
        
        
        searchTF.rx.controlEvent(.editingChanged)
            .throttle(.milliseconds(1000), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .withLatestFrom(searchTF.rx.text)
        .subscribe(onNext:{ query in
            print(self.hitSomeApi(query: query ?? "--"))
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

    }

func hitSomeApi(query: String) -> String {
        return query + " Response from API"
    }
```

When I run the app and start typing I get the the **Response from API** message with each letter or backspace button pressed! why the `throttle` delay is not working? Im I doing something wrong here?

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `Response from API` gets printed every one second for me, not whenever I type a letter. Did you type too slowly?

Comment: Maybe `debounce` (as opposed to `throttle`) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description of the problem, it seems like the `debounce` operator is more suitable than `throttle`. `debounce` only emits an element if a certain time, in which nothing has been emitted, has passed, whereas `throttle` ensures that elements are emitted at least a certain time interval apart.

I can confirm that your code using `throttle` is working as I'd expect - if I type very quickly, the "Response from API" messages appear roughly every 1 second. If I type very slowly, slower than 1 keystroke per second, then the messages come whenever I press a key. In other words, whenever there is an editing changed event, `throttle` checks to see if there was a previous one less than 1 second ago. If there is, ignore this new one.

If you use `debounce` however (the same code, just replace `throttle` with `debounce`), then after each keystroke, it would wait for 1 second to see if the text field is going to change again. It would only emit the editing changed event if it has waited and there is no more editing changed events. So if you keep typing at a pace higher than 1 keystroke per second, no elements will ever be emitted by the observable. This seems to be what you want.

You can compare these two operators on RxMarbles (they are called slightly different names there):

- [debounceTime](https://rxmarbles.com/#debounceTime)
- [throttleTime](https://rxmarbles.com/#throttleTime)

Comment: Thanks Man, using `debounce` solved my issue

Comment: In general, if the Observable emits data then use `debounce`, if it emits Void then `throttle`. Also, keep in mind that `throttle` will emit the "last value" unless you set that parameter to `false`.